# Adding a Date column that corresponds to the value in the day of the week column in R

Tags: r

How do I add a Date column that corresponds to the value in the day of the week column in R?

For example, if the WeekStarting value is “2016-01-03”, then the value in the Date column for the Monday that comes after “2016-01-03” should have a value of “2016-01-04”.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YErsJ.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try first just adding a column that has the consecutive dates

```
seq(as.Date("2016/1/3"), as.Date("2016/1/17"), "days")
```